# Passing reactives between Shiny modules to get dynamic updates

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to R and Shiny, and I'm writing a Shiny app that allows the user to create/read/update/delete records in a MariaDB database. When the user adds a record, I want the UI to display the updated contents of the table.

It works if all the code is in a single app.R, but when I break it into Shiny modules (saveNew and displaytbl), I can't get the datatable to automatically update, probably because I haven't figured out the correct reactive 'plumbing' that I need to pass data between modules.

app.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    saveNewUI("saveNew")),
  fluidRow(
    displaytblUI("displaytbl")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Load initial contents from database
  tibl <- reactiveVal(loadSites())
  
  # Display table
  observeEvent(tibl(), { # without observe(), can't access tibl outside reactive context
    displaytblServer("displaytbl", tibl())
  })
  
  # Save a new record to the table, and update the tibl reactiveVal
  tibl(saveNewServer("saveNew"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

displaytbl.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

displaytblUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    DT::dataTableOutput(ns("datatable"))
  )
}

displaytblServer <- function(id, datatable) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(datatable, {
      output$datatable <- renderDataTable(datatable())
    })
  })
}
```

saveNew.R:

```
library(shiny)

saveNewUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(ns("siteName"), "Add a site"),
    actionButton(ns("btnSave"), "Save"),
  )
}

saveNewServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$btnSave, {
      saveSite(input$siteName)
    })
    # Return the updated database table 
    reactive(loadSites())
  })
}
```

database.R (helper functions):

```
loadSites <- function() {
  query <- "SELECT * FROM names"
  res <- as_tibble(dbGetQuery(pool, query))
}

saveSite <- function(siteName) {
  query <- paste0("INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES (?)")
  params <- list(siteName)
  dbExecute(pool, query, params)
}
```

Expecting the datatable to update when the user clicks the Save button. The database gets updated, but the datatable in the UI does not (until I reload/refresh the app).

Comment: Where you do `displaytblServer("displaytbl", tibl())`, you should pass the reactive input *without* (), and inside that module, it should be `observeEvent(datatable(),...`. The idea is you pass a reactive expression to a module, and evaluate it inside the module.

Comment: In fact this block: `observeEvent(datatable, {
      output$datatable <- renderDataTable(datatable())
    })` should be without the `observeEvent` entirely. The datatable is already redrawn when the reactive datatable() changes

Comment: @RemkoDuursma Thank you! OK, I changed the call to this: `displaytblServer("displaytbl", tibl)` and the body of moduleServer to just: `output$datatable <- renderDataTable(datatable())`. Now I get `Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)`. The bottom of the stack trace is this:
`101: func
   88: renderFunc
   87: renderFunc
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$displaytbl-datatable
    1: shiny::runApp
`

Comment: I'll post the first part of the output below. It's as if renderDataTable() is seeing datatable() as the function loadSites(), rather than the _result_ of loadSites().
`Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3348
function ()  
 - attr(*, "observable")=Classes 'Observable', 'R6' reactive({
    loadSites()
}) 
 - attr(*, "cacheHint")=List of 1
  ..$ userExpr: language {  loadSites() }
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "reactiveExpr" "reactive" "function"
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)
`
< stack trace follows here >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After incorporating suggestions from @remko-duursma, I was able to get rid of my error by removing the observeEvent() from my app server(), and also passing the tibl reactiveVal as an argument to saveNewServer(), where it's used to update the database. My working code is below.

app server function:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Load initial contents from database
  tibl <- reactiveVal(loadSites())
  
  # Display table
  displaytblServer("displaytbl", tibl)
  
  saveNewServer("saveNew", tibl)
}
```

saveNewServer function:

```
saveNewServer <- function(id, tibl) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$btnSave, {
      saveSite(input$siteName)
      tibl(loadSites())
    })
  })
}
```

displaytblServer function:

```
displaytblServer <- function(id, datatable) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$datatable <- renderDataTable(datatable())
  })
}
```